# ios:NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest is not working why?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I am doing Json parsing by using this  url @"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.clickgamer.AngryBirds".

I wrote the below code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.clickgamer.AngryBirds"]; //This URL only for testing
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSError *errorReturned = nil;
    NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];

    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Data = %@ ", [[jsonArray objectForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"version"]);

}];
```

But I got data is empty(i.e Data ()).

Please help me.

thanks
Dronavalli

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are printing in console with the keys those not exist in json response:-

Print whole dictionary like:-

```
NSLog(@"Data = %@ ",jsonArray);
```

Comment: sorry i got the below error    "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'"

Comment: Same Code Working fine at my end: Data = (
    "5.0.1"
)

Comment: Sorry i got the same error.But i do not know why.Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Ayan Khan its work fine but code is not working in iPad.I have to check it.